# Prove the set identity $(A \cap B) \setminus (B\cap C) = A \cap (B \setminus C)$

Tags: elementary-set-theory, logic

> Prove the set identity $(A \cap B) \setminus (B\cap C) = A \cap (B \setminus C)$

Attempt at proof:

For some element $x\in (A \cap B) \setminus (B\cap C)$:
$$x\in (A \cap B) \setminus (B\cap C) \implies x \in (A \cap B) \land x \notin (B\cap C)$$ $$\implies x \in A \land x\in B \land x \notin B \land x \notin C$$

For some element $x\in A \cap (B \setminus C)$:
$$A \cap (B \setminus C) \implies x \in A \land x \in (B \setminus C) \implies x \in A \land x\in B \land X \notin C$$

The first part of the proof seems to have a contradiction with $x\in B \land x \notin B$ and I am not sure how to prove further

Comment: You use $x\not\in(B\cap C)\implies x\not\in B \land x\not\in C$. This is false. It should be something like
$$
x\not\in(B\cap C) \iff \lnot(x\in B \land x \in C) \iff x\not\in B \lor x\not\in C.
$$

Comment: @JohnGriffin Why does it change to $\lor$

Comment: De Morgan's Law:
$$\lnot (p \lor q) \equiv \lnot p \land \lnot q$$
$$\lnot (p \land q) \equiv \lnot p \lor \lnot q$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Be careful while using De Morgan's Law.
(Please refer to the Venn diagram attached blow.)
$$
x\in (A \cap B) \setminus (B\cap C)
\Leftrightarrow x\in (A \cap B) \land x \notin (B\cap C) \Leftrightarrow (x \in A \land x\in B) \land (x \notin B \lor x \notin C) \Leftrightarrow x\in A \land x\in B \land x\notin C \Leftrightarrow x\in A \land (x\in B \land x\notin C) \Leftrightarrow x\in A \land x\in (B \setminus C) \Leftrightarrow x\in A \cap (B \setminus C)
$$
[image]

Comment: You can draw a Venn Diagram and get clear intuition from that.

Comment: Can you show me a Venn Diagram for that, I am not sure how to make one.

Comment: I drew a picture for you.

Answer (score 3):

Just use the fact that $X \setminus Y = X \cap Y^c$. Thus we get \begin{align}
(A \cap B) \setminus (B \cap C) &= (A \cap B) \cap (B \cap C)^{c} \\ &= (A \cap B) \cap (B^{c} \cup C^{c}) \\ &= ((A \cap B) \cap B^c) \cup ((A \cap B) \cap C^c)\\ &= (\emptyset) \cup (A \cap (B \cap C^c)) \\ &= A \cap (B \setminus C)\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

$\begin{array}
\ x \in (A \cap B) \land x \notin (B\cap C) &\iff x \in (A \cap B) \land \lnot \big(x \in (B\cap C)\big)\\
&\iff(x\in A \land x\in B) \land \lnot (x\in B \land x\in C) \\
&\iff (x\in A \land x\in B) \land (x\notin B \lor x\notin C) \\
&\iff \big((x\in A \land x\in B) \land x\notin B \big) \lor \big( (x\in A \land x\in B) \land x\notin C \big) \\
&\iff F \lor \big( x\in A \land x\in B \land x\notin C \big) \\
\end{array}$

I'm sure you could take over from here!

Comment: What is $F$,  False?

Comment: @lakada That's correct, due to $x\in B \land x \notin B$.